# What is need to build native extension for Gems on Windows? (RubyGems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

More and more gems I run into requires building "native extensive", such as RedCloth.  Are there tools that are open-source or free that is sufficient to do that?  I heard MS Visual Studio also has a free version.  Will that be enough to build native extensions?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ruby with the [RubyInstaller](http://RubyInstaller.Org/) (as you should), then the [DevKit](http://RubyInstaller.Org/add-ons/devkit/) has everything you need.

If you use the [obsolete MSVC6 builds](ftp://FTP.Ruby-Lang.Org/pub/ruby/binaries/mswin32/), then you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0, because newer versions of MSVC are incompatible. Good luck finding that, though, MSVC6 isn't even from this millenium.

Comment: by the way I just saw in Rails Tutorial's screencast http://railstutorial.org/screencasts that cygwin installation has a gcc option